# An interesting problem for the majorant method (limitation)

Tags: inequality, desmos

$\begin{cases} y\geq 4x^4+4yx^2+\frac{1}{2}\\y^2-2x^2\leq \frac{1}{4}\end{cases}$

In desmos, it is clearly visible that this is a limitation task (and the task is in the limitations section). I have an assumption that

$4x^4+4yx^2+\frac{1}{2}-y\geq0$, if $y^2-2x^2\leq \frac{1}{4}$

but this is just a guess. I tried to distribute the sum of the squares, but I couldn't. I tried to replace the second inequality with the first one, but nothing worked. I will be glad if you can help!

Comment: It is easily seen in Desmos (see [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pe0mpxfqj7)) that the answer to your question is the points (-1, -1.5), (0, 0.5), and (1, -1.5). I don't see any problem.